# Firebase Security & Rules -Double-

Tags: security, firebase, double

How  can I do to avoid decimals on Firebase Security Rules?

I am using isNumber on node that should accept Integer values, but I also accept Decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent non-integer numeric values from being accepted, I believe the following rule would work:

```
".validate": "newData.isNumber() && newData.val() % 1.0 === 0.0"
```